# Как задать ключи элементам массива?

Tags: javascript

Есть строка:

```
1,9,8
```

Мне нужно её разбить на массив, полагаю функцией split.

Но как первому элементу задать имя ключа **weight**, второму **length**, третьему **id**?

Comment: в масиве нету ключей, создайте обьект с такими свойствами

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно написать свою функцию и использовать [деструктуризацию параметров](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) и [новую нотацию при создании литерала объекта](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015)

Например:

```js
function GetResult([weight, length, id]) {
  return {
    weight,
    length,
    id
  };
}

console.log(GetResult('1,2,3'.split(',')));
console.log(GetResult('4,7,9'.split(',')));
console.log(GetResult(['a', 'b', 'c']));
```